# How do I print an accessor method into a main program?

Tags: java, char, tostring

I am having trouble getting an accessor method to return a character in a toString into a main class.

```
public class Alpha
{
  .
  .
  .
  public char getLetter()  
  {  
      return letter;  
  }  

  public String toString()
  {
    String str = "This is the letter " + letter;
    return str;
  }
```

Second program

```
public class AlphaDemo
{
  public static main........
  {
    Alpha xxNewLetter = new Alpha(.....);
    System.out.println(xxNewLetter);
  }
}
```

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What does your constructor look like? What is being outputted? What you have so far looks correct.

Comment: And you are also missing the keyword void in your main method signature

Comment: public Letters( String firstLetter)
 {
  this.firstLetter =  firstLetter;
        }

Comment: Why is your constructor named Letters? Your class name is Alpha.

Comment: I'm just using random names. I'm trying to print out all the accessor methods I am using in a program but the only one I am have a lot of problems with is the character (char). I am making a program that list a group of people that took a test based on their last name, ID number, and score. I was able to print out everything except for the letter grade. So far everything I have done doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Well your class's constructor needs to have a same name as the class. What are you passing to the Alpha constructor in main? And if your instance variable is a String, you won't be able to use it as a char

Answer (score 0):

Your classes should be like follows.

```
public class Alpha {
    char letter;

    public Alpha(char letter) {
        this.letter = letter;
    }

    public char getLetter() {
        return letter;
    }

    public String toString() {
        String str = "This is the letter " + letter;
        return str;
    }
}
```

And Alpha Demo

```
public class AlphaDemo {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        Alpha xxNewLetter = new Alpha('A');
        System.out.println(xxNewLetter);
    }
}
```